# Como utilizar Facades do Laravel fora de sua estrutura?

Tags: laravel

Estou tentando utilizar algumas classes da "estrutura do laravel" em outros arquivos, mas não estou obtendo sucesso.

Por exemplo:
Criei um arquivo `public/teste.php` com o seguinte código:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB;

$dbInstance = new DB;

var_dump($dbInstance);
```

Isso dá o seguinte retorno:

> object(Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB)#2 (0) { }

Mas quando eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB;

$dbInstance = new DB;

var_dump($dbInstance);

$pessoas = DB::table("pessoas")->get();

var_dump($pessoas);
```

Dá o seguinte resultado:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'A facade root has not been set.' in C:\wamp\www\PROJETO\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:210 
 Stack trace: 
 #0 C:\wamp\www\PROJETO\public\teste.php(11): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('table', Array) 
 #1 C:\wamp\www\PROJETO\public\teste.php(11): Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('pessoas') 
 #2 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\PROJETO\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 210
```

Alguém tem ideia de onde estou errando?

Eu gostaria de utilizar também minhas Model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é tão simples assim Anderson. O Laravel como qualquer outro framework geralmente precisa ser inicializado, pois existem muitas outras coisas que precisam estar rodando antes de usar as classes propriamente ditas.

No caso do Laravel temos o Dependency Injection, Providers que chamam os arquivos de Rotas, Middlewares, etc.

Para entender melhor como o Laravel é iniciado, leia a [seguinte página da documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/master/lifecycle) que fala sobre o ciclo de vida da requisição.

Em resumo, **não precisa reinventar a roda**. Entenda e crie sua aplicação a partir da estrutura do Laravel.

Caso você deseje só utilizar um componente separado do Laravel, como o [de Database](https://github.com/illuminate/database), é possível utilizar os sub módulos do Illuminate. Veja as instruções de uso retirada do repositório:

```
<?php

// Mudar aqui para o autoloader do composer
require 'vendor/autoload.php'

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);

// Set the event dispatcher used by Eloquent models... (optional)
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

A partir dai, você consegue utilizar de forma diferente o `DB::` e seus Models em Eloquent.

**Nota:** Isso **não** habilita o uso das Facades. Utilizar elas fora do framework não é possível pois existem outras integrações que precisam ser seguidas.

Comment: Li a documentação que você mencionou e ainda não consegui entender plenamente o ciclo de vida de uma aplicação laravel.

Para o meu problema, telvez eu precisa utilizar essa classe aqui "DatabaseManager", também não é simples utilizada??


Meu código não está dentro do controller pois quero utilizar um Framework que fiz, e achei muito complicado incorporar ele dentro do laravel, por isso quero utilizar por fora... 

Por isso estou tentando acessar o banco de dados por fora dos controllers.

Comment: No seu caso você pode utilizar somente o componente de database https://github.com/illuminate/database

Comment: @gmsantos me parece que o Laravel, apesar de ser separado, como o próprio nome dos repositórios no github diz é [ReadOnly]

Comment: @gmsantos você já conseguiu utilizar esse componente ai? não estou conseguindo.. Está dando o seguinte erro: Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager' not found .... Segui a documentação mas n fui feliz. Como você fez?

Comment: Consegui, estava faltando isso: 
require ....... '/vendor/autoload.php';    Para poder ajudar outras pessoas, qual o melhor lugar para eu colocar essa resposta?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters é um split do repo principal. Ele não aceita contribuições daquele repo, somente no principal... por isso o read-only

Comment: @AndersonSouza mais tarde eu edito a resposta.